# Codemagic - Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a Provisioning Profile

Tags: flutter, codemagic, flutter-ios

I want to test my flutter app on an ios device. I am building via Codemagic since I don't have a mac.
I don't have a mac but I managed to generate a development certificate via a virtual machine, and upload it for manual signing on CodeMagic

However, everytime I build using CodeMagic, I got the following error.

Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a
Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team

I don't have an apple developer subscription also. I just want to test the app on my ios device.